# Can't set routes when POSTing from Android to a custom Ruby controller

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create users on a Ruby server (Heroku) from an Android app. I already have a users controller for creating users from the website. I am attempting to create a custom controller that responds with JSON to the Android app.

When I attempt to register from the app, logcat gives me the appname/public/500.html file from the server. When I run `rake routes` this is the output:

`app_registration_create POST   /app_registration/create(.:format) app_registration#create`

But the app never reaches that route.

I have tried several different ways and this is the current set up of the routes file:

```
post 'app_registration/create'
```

I'm pretty sure the Android side is okay, but I could be wrong. 
Any ideas? If more code samples are required, let me know.

Comment: Is this your rails app, or do you have access to the source code or log files? Could you try making a POST request and watching the logs to see what happens?

Comment: It is my rails app. I got it working, in that I can now create users from the Android app. I made a mess of the params hash. However, although it is now creating users remotely, it is still returning the 500.html file as opposed to the rendered JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Your API should be completely client-agnostic - have you successfully posted using any other tools? If you want to post your routes file and controllers, I'll take a look at them.